# Как скачать базу даных Википедии?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server

Как скачать базу даных Википедии (английской) для того, чтобы в SQL Management Studio можно было с базой даных работать?

Comment: [Как сделать копию Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8E_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: *mysql* зачем тут?

Comment: @TimurVI Может возьмёте информацию оттуда и оформите как ответ?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov не могу, спасибо